# c++ template function with predicate support

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a priority queue using template.I tried but i am getting some error , i want to pass custom predicate support for less function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename lessFunction>
class MyClass
{
    typedef std::size_t     size_type;
public:
    void push( const T& t) {
        //
        size_type index ;//(some value .. say 5)
        //...//
        if(lessFunction(m_buffer[index], t))
        {
            /// do something
        }
    }

private:
    T m_buffer[N];
};

struct myCompare
{
    bool operator() (int& x, const int& y) {
        return abs(x) < abs(y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int , 8, myCompare> obj;
    obj.push(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
/home/sanju/code/circular-buffer/main.cpp:17: error: no matching function for call to 'myCompare::myCompare(int&, const int&)'
         if(lessFunction(m_buffer[index], t))
```

Please correct me. And i have one more question
how can this template use a functor as well as function as lessFunction ?

Comment: lessFunction is a *type*. To call `lessFunction::operator()` you need an *object*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class and then use the overloaded () operator in your push member function.

```
...
lessFunction f ;
if (f(m_buffer[index], t))
...
```

The operator overloaded function is not a static member function and hence requires an instance of the class be declared to be called.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are going to doing this every time you call the push function you make `f` a class member so you don't have to create it every time you call the function.

Comment: Precisely, the operator overloaded function *cannot* be a static function.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `lessFunction::operator(int&, const int&)` on a object because operator overloading function may not be static. Therefore, you can create an object of it like:

```
 class MyClass
 {
     lessFunction comparator;
 };
```

and, when needed, call it this way:

```
if ( comparator(m_buffer[index], t) )
```

You can also declare it as a local variable but you'd better keep just one instance of it accessible throughout the class.
Finally, you may consider using [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), maybe as default template parameter, so that you don't have to reimplement it as you're doing for `myCompare`.

`template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename lessFunction = std::less<T>>
class MyClass`